# what is the best way to store a 8 queen problem's board in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to solve [8 queen problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) with search algorithms such as [iterative-deepening search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) or [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).
I've given a board and I should find the minimum number of moves to get a board which in no queens threat each other.
I don't know what data structure or package should I use to store my board in python.

I'm going to print and save visited boards and I think I should use the best data structure for optimizing time and space.

I started with [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) because my data was given in csv.
Then I noticed I should check identical boards and I switched to [numpy.array()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#array-creation) for easy comparing boards. Another way is to use simple python list of tuples:

```
[(q1_x, q1_y), (q2_x, q2_y), ....(q8_x, q8_y)]
```

But  I don't know which is this the best solution for this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `numpy` is mostly useful for working with large arrays and performing operations on a whole vector. If you only need to store a board state as a list of coordinates of 8 queens, it seems to me that a list of tuples would work.

Comment: The state of a valid board can be represented as a simple list of 8 elements - the column number for each row.

Comment: @hpaulj What if I have multiple queens in one row??.

Comment: They'll annihilate each other!  A numpy array is a convenient form for displaying a board, but it isn't particularly good for searching.

Answer (score 1):

#### To represent legal states:

A fast and compact way of storing queen positions on a chessboard is a simple array (or list), where the index represents the column number, and the value the row number where a queen is located. you may want to use `-1` to mark if no queen is present in a column:

For instance: `queens = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` represents the following configuration:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 Q
1   Q
2     Q
3       Q
4         Q
5           Q
6             Q
7               Q
```

You could similarly use a `numpy` array of 8 bits integers

#### [edit] to represent all states:

you can compactly use an array of 8 binary number between `0` and `255` where the ones represent the column position of a queen:

```
import random

class Queens:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = [bin(random.randrange(0, 256))[2:].zfill(8) for _ in range(8)]
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return'\n'.join(self.config)
    
    def __str__(self):
        result = ['  ' + ' '.join(str(idx) for idx in range(8))]
        for rdx, elt in enumerate(self.config):
            a = elt.replace('1', 'Q ')
            a = a.replace('0', '  ')
            a = str(rdx) + ' ' + a
            result.append(a)
        return'\n'.join(result)
                
q = Queens()
print(repr(q), end='\n\n')
print(q)
```

**output:**

```
01010001
10000010
01000010
10100001
01011110
10001110
01010110
11000000

  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0   Q   Q       Q 
1 Q           Q   
2   Q         Q   
3 Q   Q         Q 
4   Q   Q Q Q Q   
5 Q       Q Q Q   
6   Q   Q   Q Q   
7 Q Q
```

Comment: What if I have two queens in one column? How should I store those queens in such an array?

Comment: That position is illegal: two queens in a column are threatening each other; the same is true for two queens in the same row: all values in the array must be distinct. These two characteristics of the data structure make it very efficient to check for the validity of a configuration for rows and columns.

Comment: As I said, I'm implementing search algorithms and in these algorithms, most of my states are illegal states. I'm trying to find the legal states among other states.

Comment: @k47 I added a compact representation of all states

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is Numba: http://numba.pydata.org/. It allows to code naive `for` loops which are slow in pure python and still get good performance.